# Is it possible to create an object that is a subset of another object without losing the references in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object in javascript that has a bunch of data I need.  I would like to be able to make a second object that contains a subset of the data from the first object without losing the references.  For example:

```
var test1 = {foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'};
var test2 = {foo: test1.foo};
```

Unfortunately creating test2 to in this way loses the reference and test2.foo is bound to the value 'foo' not to the reference for the value 'foo'.  That means that the property foo doesn't stay in sync between the two object.

```
test1.foo = 'new value';
test2.foo; // <= 'foo'
```

I have tried a bunch of stuff to get this working with no luck.  I'm not sure if the language supports this but maybe someone has a clever way to achieve this.

Comment: 1. this is not possible 2. this whole idea sounds broken from the very beginning. So it probably would be better to rethink it entirely.

Comment: var test1 = {foo: ['foo'], bar: 'bar'};
var test2 = {foo: test1.foo};
test1.foo[0] = 'new value';
test2.foo;

Comment: You can achieve syntax you want with properties (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2Fget), but as @zerkms says there are likely better ways of achieving what you actually need.

Comment: Or check out most of MVVM libraries (like KnockoutJs) to see how they deal with creating observable objects.

Comment: `test2.foo` is not a reference to `test1.foo`; it is a new value, but it points to the same object.

Comment: I think you are right @Alexei Levenkov.  Using getters and setters seems pretty promising.  I'll test this further tomorrow after sleeps.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok.  I have a pretty good solution to this issue.  All credit goes to @Alexei Levenkov who made the suggestion of using getters and setters.

```
var test1 = {foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'};
var test2 = {get foo(){return test1.foo;}, set foo(x){test1.foo = x;}};
```

By using getters and setters test1.foo and test2.foo will stay in sync.

```
test1.foo = 'new value';
test2.foo; // <= 'new value'
test2.foo = 'new new value';
test1.foo; // <= 'new new value'
```

Super duper!!!